# Norm of product of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have two matrix $A$ and $\delta A$ from rang $n \times n$, $A$ nonsingular. And two non zero vectors $x$ and $\delta x$ both from $R^{n}$ that :
$$Ax=b$$
$$(A+\delta A)(x+\delta x)=b $$

proof that for vector b from $R^{n}$:
$$ \frac{||\delta x||}{||x+\delta x ||}\le k (A)\frac{||\delta A||}{||A||}$$
where $k(A)$ condition number of matrix $A$, for some norm.

Obviously, if I open brackets and make some simple combination I get:
$$A \delta x=-\delta A(x+\delta x)$$
if I take the norm of both sides I get:
$$||A \delta x||=||\delta A(x+\delta x)||$$
If its possible make this step:
$$||A|| \cdot|| \delta x||=||\delta A||\cdot||(x+\delta x)||$$
and with $k(A)\ge 1$ we have proof statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $A$ is nonsingular, we have
\begin{aligned}
\|\delta x\|
&=\|A^{-1}\delta A(x+\delta x)\|\\
&\le\|A^{-1}\|\|\delta A\|\|x+\delta x\|\\
&=\frac{k(A)}{\|A\|}\|\delta A\|\|x+\delta x\|.
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

The equality isn't true, but we do have $\|Ax\| \leq \|A\| \|x\|$, which suffices for your purposes.